# Infinite while loop in Matlab, counter doesn't exit loop

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a function of the Gauss Seidel method of solving a linear system of equations of the form Ax=b, x being the unknown we are looking for. 
I am having a problem with the while loop in my function, it seems that it runs infinitely. I can't seem to figure out why.

This is my function for creating the coefficient matrix A and the column vectors x and b, all with the same number of rows of course. No problem with this one.

```
function [A, b, x0] = test_system(n)

u = ones(n, 1);

A = spdiags([u 4*u u], [-1 0 1], n, n);

b = zeros(n, 1);
b(1) = 3;
b(2 : 2 : end-2) = -2;
b(3 : 2 : end-1) = 2;
b(end) = -3;

x0 = ones(n, 1);
```

This is my function for solving the system. I have included all of it just in case, but I believe the real problem is within the while loop at the very end which runs infinitely when I execute the function. The counter doesn't break away from it either. I can't really see what its problem is. Any clues?
Be gentle, I'm new at Matlab :)

```
function [x] = GaussSeidel(A,b,x0,tol)

% implementation of the GaussSeidel iterative method
% for solving a linear system of equations Ax = b
%INPUTS:
%   A: coefficient matrix
%   b: column vector of constants
%   x0: setup for the unknown vector (using vector of ones)
%   tol: result must be within 'tol' of correct answer.

%OUTPUTS:
%   x: unknown

%check that A is a matrix
if ~(ismatrix(A))
    error('A is not a matrix');
end

%check that A is square
[m,n] = size(A);
if m ~= n 
    error('Matrix A is not square');
end

%check that b is a column vector
if ~(iscolumn(b))
    error('b is not a column vector');
end

%check that x0 is a column vector
if ~(iscolumn(x0))
    error('x0 is not a column vector');
end

%check that A, b and x0 agree in size
[rowA,colA] = size(A);
[rowb,colb] = size(b);
[rowx0,colx0] = size(x0);

if ~isequal(colA,rowb)||~isequal(rowb,rowx0)
    error('matrix dimensions of A, b and xo do not agree');
end

%check that A and b have real entries
if ~isreal(A) || ~isreal(b)
    error('matrix A or vector b do not have real entries');
end

%check that the provided tolerance is positive
if tol <= 0 
    error('tolerance must be positive');
end

%check that A is strictly diagonally dominant
absoluteA = abs(A);
row_sum=sum(absoluteA,2);
diagonal=diag(absoluteA);

if ~all(2*diagonal > row_sum)  
    warning('matrix A is not strictly diagonally dominant');
end


L = tril(A,-1);
U = triu(A,+1);
D = diag(diag(A));

x = x0;

M1 = inv(D).*L;
M2 = inv(D).*U;
M3 = D\b;

k = 0;     %iterations counter

disp(size(M1));
disp(size(M2));
disp(size(M3));
disp(size(x));


while (norm(A*x - b) > tol)
    for i=1:n
        x(i) = - M1(i,:).*x - M2(i,:).*x + M3(i,:);
    end
    k=k+1;
    if(k >= 10e4)
        error('too many iterations carried out');
    end 
end     

end     %end function
```

Comment: For me it doesn't run past the for loop. Something is wrong with the line "x(i) = - M1(i,:).*x - M2(i,:).*x + M3(i,:);", the dimensions don't match. Maybe you mean "\*" instead of ".\*"

Comment: By the way: The line "M3 = D\b;" seems a bit weird. If you could make use of the "\" operator, the best way to program a linear solver would be "x=A\b". I'd rather use "M3 = b./diag(A)" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Coding Discussion

The source of the coding error is the use of element-wise operations instead of matrix-matrix and matrix-vector operations.
These operations produce zero-matrices, so no progress is made.
The `M` matrices should be defined by

```
M1 = inv(D)*L;  % Note that D\L is more efficient
M2 = inv(D)*U;  % Note that D\U is more efficient
M3 = D\b;
```

and the iterator performing the update should be

```
x(i) = - M1(i,:)*x - M2(i,:)*x + M3(i,:);
```

### Method Discussion

I also think it is worth mentioning that the code is currently implementing the [Jacobi Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) since the updater has the form

[image: Jacobi update formula]

while a [Gauss-Seidel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) update has the form

[image: Gauss-Seidel update formula].

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were right, the problem was in the M1 and M2 calculations.
Also, I checked the code is indeed implementing the jacobi method, however we were given a pseudocode to follow by our teacher in class so I just coded what he wrote there. I guess he got mixed up in the methods. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome!  If you could except this answer so I can get the rep, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have 50 reputation so I can not comment this.

The line `if(k >= 10e4)`, I think this does not make what you think it would. `10e4` is 100,000 and `1e4` is 10,000. This will be the reason why you think your counter does not work. Matlab ist still running because it’s running further than you think it will. Also I run in the same Problem knedlsepp already pointed out.